# How to correct implement provider logic using generics in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I try to implement logic where some different objects can receive their unique configs.

I have a lot of objects with different types, which can request their own configuration object.

```
//Provider
protocol ConfigProvider {
    func config<R: ConfigReciever>(for reciever: R) -> R.ConfigType
}

class Factory {

}

extension Factory: ConfigProvider {
    func config<R: ConfigReciever>(for reciever: R) -> R.ConfigType {
        //How switch?
        return Config1(info: "hey") as! R.ConfigType
    }
}

//Reciever
protocol ConfigReciever: class {
    associatedtype ConfigType
    var dataSource: ConfigProvider? { get set }
}

struct Config1 {
    let info: String
}

class Object1: ConfigReciever {
    typealias ConfigType = Config1
    var dataSource: ConfigProvider?

    func execute() {
        let config = dataSource?.config(for: self)
        print("\(config!.info)")
    }
}
```

But have some problems with correct implement `Provider` logic.
I don't know how switch reciever to create correct Config type.
Is this any options?

I know, that i can make this without generics (for example with enum of configTypes), but i don't want to make unnecessary casts.

Comment: You should declare some common interface for all `ConfigType`s. And it must include some common generic constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an intermediate protocol

```
// Wrapper container
protocol Container { }

extension String: Container { }
extension Int: Container { }

// Implementation

    //Provider
    protocol ConfigProvider {
        func config<R>(for reciever: R) -> Configuration where R : ConfigReciever, R.ConfigType: Configuration
    }

    class Factory { }

    extension Factory: ConfigProvider {
        func config<R>(for reciever: R) -> Configuration where R : ConfigReciever, R.ConfigType: Configuration {
            return Config1(info: "hey")
        }
    }

    //Reciever
    protocol ConfigReciever: class {
        associatedtype ConfigType
        var dataSource: ConfigProvider? { get set }
    }

    protocol Configuration {
        var info: Container { get set }
    }

    struct Config1: Configuration {
        var info: String
    }

    class Object1: ConfigReciever {
        typealias ConfigType = Config1
        var dataSource: ConfigProvider?

        func execute() {
            let config = dataSource?.config(for: self)
// here you should case into wanted structure:
if let stringInfo = config?.info as? String {
            print("\(stringInfo)")
    }
        }
    }

    let factory = Factory()
    let obj = Object1()

    obj.dataSource = factory

    obj.execute()
```

Comment: `ConfigType: Configuration` should be inside `ConfigReciever` declaration, on `associatedtype` line.

Comment: it's good solution. but i want to use `Config`'s with different properties and types, so i can't conform `Configuration` 
For example: `Config1(info: String)` and `Config2(amount: Int)`

Comment: @Daivest I've updated the post. I added a `Container` wrapper protocol